# Como usar o Elasticsearch junto ao MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json, elasticsearch

Estou querendo usar o elasticsearch para ver se consigo agilidade e rapidez nas minhas consultas ao MySQL.

Comecei a ver algumas coisas, porém achei um pouco confuso a questão de integração com o MySQL, alguém tem alguma experiência com elasticsearch e pode explicar como integrar elasticsearch com o MySQL?

Comment: Você tem algum problema específico que possa mostrar aqui? A pergunta assim está muito geral/abrangente... `alguém tem alguma experiencia com elasticsearch?` - e está fora do ambito deste site que procura responder a perguntas mais específicas... Dê uma olhada aqui: __http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask__

Comment: fiz os testes com a api php de busca e post esta tudo certo.
a minha duvida e como integrar isso com o mysql.

Comment: Use a edição da pergunta para colocar mais detalhes para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Juntei o seu comentário à pergunta. Assim ficou um pouco mais específico :) Pode mudar se achar que fiz mal.

Comment: magina obrigado sem problemas

Answer (score 8):

Talvez você precise melhorar um pouco sua pergunta colocando mais informações como por exemplo a linguagem em que sua aplicação foi escrita (falo da aplicação que atualmente acessa esse banco de dados).

Apesar disso, vou tentar dar uma resposta genérica que espero que ajude.

O elasticsearch é um servidor de buscas distribuído, REST, software livre/código aberto baseado no Apache Lucene.

Agora, falando de uma forma bem simples, imagina que ele é uma caixa-preta. 
Você vai apenas colocar as informações que você quer armazenar e depois vai poder recuperá-las com o id, de modo parecido com o que você faz com o Mysql. A principal vantagem como você mesmo falou, é que você pode fazer buscas textuais rápidas (como o google ;P).

Outra diferença é que você não tem um SQL (e a princípio não precisa de schema). Para cadastrar itens no elasticsearch você simplesmente submete um json via url (HTTP) com as informações que você quer salvar e buscar posteriormente.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/comidas/doce/1' -d '{
    "nome": "Sorvete",
    "descricao": "São deliciosos!",
}'
```

Da mesma forma, na hora de realizar a busca, é só passar uma url com o que você quer buscar (e talvez algumas opções que não vale discutir aqui.)

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/comidas/_search?q=descricao:deliciosos'

# Resposta

{
   "took":14,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":1,
      "max_score":0.19178301,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"comidas",
            "_type":"doce",
            "_id":"1",
            "_score":0.19178301,
            "_source":{
               "nome":"Sorvete",
               "descricao":"São deliciosos!"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

O resumo é que na solução mais direta, você tem que salvar sua informação (por exemplo, os dados de um funcionário) tanto no mysql quanto no elasticsearch. Essa seria uma responsabilidade da sua aplicação (a mesma que utiliza o mysql).

Da mesma forma, quando alguma coisa for alterada no banco (um funcionário mudou de endereço), você também precisa salvar esses dados no elasticsearch.

Um pouco chato né? Para facilitar um pouco o trabalho de quem precisa ter as informações de algum lugar inseridas automaticamente também no elasticsearch existem os rivers, que são plugins que dada uma fonte, "alimentam" automaticamente o elasticsearch.

Existe um river específico para alguns bancos de dados que é o https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc .

Com esse plugin instalado e configurado no elasticsearch, conforme seu banco for sendo alterado as mudanças vão sendo sincronizadas com o elasticsearch.
Daí para você só resta o trabalho de fazer as consultas via HTTP na sua aplicação.

Um tutorial (em inglês) de como começar a usar esse plugin pode ser encontrado em https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart

Apesar desse plugin bacana existir, recomendo MUITO você tentar conhecer um pouco mais sobre o elasticsearch, e é muito útil entender o que o plugin está fazendo por trás para você.

A maior parte dos tutoriais (e primeiros passos) de elasticsearch estão em inglês, mas encontrei esses dos links em português que são legais.

- [Introdução ao ElasticSearch - Busca textual em sua aplicação](http://blog.victordolirio.com/2012/10/um-google-na-sua-aplicacao-com-o.html)
- [Introdução ao Elasticsearch](https://github.com/lucassmagal/blog/blob/master/pages/introducao-ao-elasticsearch.md)